# By which software these product photos were created?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-editing, product-design, adobe-dimension

I am beginner in designing field and want to learn how these product photos were designed? Which software is used to create these types of product images?

If I have white background photos like this one

[image]

Then how can I create images like these ones?

[image]

[image]

More similar product photos available here: https://www.invicta-interior.com/de/SITZMOeBEL/Sofa

Please suggest me best softwares for this type of designing work,

Many thanks!

Comment: Its impossible to know. The number of possible ways to do it is staggering.

Comment: You start by finding a room that has a lamp and pictures and couch and rug and everything like that, then you use a camera to take a picture of it. Then you edit the photo for lighting and contrast and so on in your photo editor of choice.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that these particular images are made in 3d: you can notice weird bumpiness of materials, weird fur, etc. My guess is 3dsMax (models and materials) + Vray (rendering): a popular combo for these type of shots.

Comment: I'd say 3D as well.. seeing as the sofa is two different sizes.... probably something along the lines of [**this**](https://cedreo.com/home-decorating-software/?campaignid=1760054786&adgroupid=74461247928&adid=341982279314&utm_term=3d%20home%20interior%20design%20software&utm_campaign=US+%7C+Interior+Design&utm_medium=ppc&utm_source=adwords&hsa_ad=341982279314&hsa_kw=3d%20home%20interior%20design%20software&hsa_ver=3&hsa_acc=6133015900&hsa_cam=1760054786&hsa_mt=p&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_grp=74461247928&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=kwd-4610379695&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI9bHZyum16wIV3xatBh2UfQbgEAAYASAAEgLWxPD_BwE)

Comment: Probably 3D, IKEA does most of its furniture catalog in 3D. Even then, there are many 3D packages that could get a similar result, so I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy when did you last update your info?

Comment: @joojaa what do you mean?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy V-ray (and 3ds max) hasnt been really in vogue in product shots for a few years now. People tend to use other path tracers nowdays.

Comment: @joojaa ah ok, sorry then

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Yes, these images are made in 3D. But I'm not sure by which software I can achieve these results. Anyway thanks for your comment, its really helpful :)

Comment: try asking @joojaa : it seems that he knows what's trendy in this area now

Comment: Typically product designers seem to be using keyshot for this kind of stuff. And then model in whatever cad they were using anyway

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is actual studio photography. Look at the shadow on the wall at the left of the couch.

Comment: @user8356 there is no sane way of differentiating a modern pathtraced image from a photograph by looking at an image.

Comment: @joojaa: You're right. Especially at low resolution on a monitor. But a lot of product scenes like that are still done as studio photos -- for realism, cost and convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already said its impossible decide surely how these are made. They can be high quality 3D models. Or the room only is a model, a furniture image (background removed) is inserted on a rendered 3D image. Or a real furniture is photographed in a real room-like studio environment.

In the linked catalog color variations of the same furniture exist. The green sofa has something realistic: The incandescent lamp colorizes the sofa below. The shift towards yellow is substantial in places which don't get full white light:

[image]

The blue version has perfect single hue blue color. I guess it's made by colorizing the green fabric area with careful selection and Hue/Saturation > Colorize adjustment in Photoshop. Nobody has bothered to bring the blue version to studio. Maybe none was even built.

[image]

Otherwise the images are pixel perfectly same as you can check with difference:

[image]

If both green and blue versions were separate rendered 3D models they both should have same effect from the yellowish lamp.

So you can take a photo of the real thing in professional studio environment. It costs money because pro quality lights and camera aren't cheap. With Photoshop  you can remove backgrounds, insert items, lights and shadows and recolorize materials.

Here's my attempt to colorize the green version to blue. The selection is made with Photoshop's Quick Selection tool, so it's quite coarse. It can be acceptable as low res web image.

[image]

3D modelling even in a low-cost floorplan software can create plausible rooms but high quality detailed model of a sofa needs more. Creating a plausible high detail model of an existing sofa needs much work and complex software. I haven't one, but I'm sure furniture makers have special 3D software which understands furniture crafting concepts with no need to tinker with general purpose monsters like Blender. Without that software it's easier to take a photo of a real sofa. But taking that photo needs good environment, equipment and of course pro level photographer skills.

If you already have a high quality furniture image (screenshots are often inferior) with white background and you want to insert the furniture into a room scene you must have a room scene which has right perspective. It cannot be adjusted - not in the furniture photo nor in an existing room scene photo. It must be shot right.

But in a floorplan program you can create the wanted scene by defining the placement of every item and the camera. It's tiresome but technically very easy. Do not expect the floorplan program has just wanted other items as ready to place 3D models, but they can be good enough. Generally a program offers thousands of items to choose from and often they can be easily recolored.

When you have a room scene which is geometrically compatible with your furniture you remove the white background with Photoshop's background removal tools. You insert the main furniture as a new top layer to the scene photo. Then you add as new layers items which cover a part of the new furniture (here the pillow, shadows, light and colorization caused by the enviroment)

Background removal is well presented in numerous web sources It isn't especially difficult if the furniture image is technically perfect. Adjusting the size, lights, shadows, color and possible color cast and reflection interactions to match between the furniture and the room can need a substantial amount of work and knowledge for plausible results. This belongs to the repertoire of professional image editor. Learning it is like learning a profession, it takes time.

BTW. The wiewing angle can be changed in 3D software with a single click. Every view with photos or combined 2D images must be made separately. Changing the view automatically in a 2D image is theoretically possible with world aware artificial intelligence software, but I guess it will be only a dream a long time.

Comment: Not so much more complex software but more skill and knowledge. Something that can not be acquired by next weeks Monday. ;)

Comment: @user287001 Thank you so much for answer, Its really helpful :)

Answer (score -2):

Think in reverse ^^
They probably cut off the couch in a picture to put on white background around instead, not the other way.

The best to do this is Adobe Photoshop (or similar).

Comment: you're probably wrong. It's much easier to take good photos on a neutral background and then compose it in a scene. But I don't believe that's how the scenes were made anyway.

Comment: separating a furniture from a room scene is possible if the photo is taken so that there's no traces (shadows, reflections, color cast, covered parts) of the environment on the furniture. Preparing the shooting is much easier if the photo is taken in a clean environment.